# How to obtain 2 dimensional arrays of Single in VB.NET exactly like in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, fortran, interop

I have some code written in VBA that uses a function of the particular environment I programmed in, which given some empty, not fixed-dimensional `Single` arrays, gives them back 2 dimensional and filled with data. It also produces a `Variant` as output.
The VBA code is:

```
Dim vDummy As Variant
Dim RealLev1() As Single, ImagLev1() As Single

vDummy = FFPOL1Array(RealLev1, ImagLev1)
```

Now, I know for sure that `FFPOL1Array`is a routine written in FORTRAN, but I cannot access to its code by any means.

I successfully managed to address the same routine in a VB.NET piece of code by writing a workaround that "links" my code to the environment mentioned above and uses its own scripting routines.

My VB.NET code would be:

```
Dim vDummy As Object
Dim RealLev1(,) As Single, ImagLev1(,) As Single

vDummy = NSI.FFPOL1Array(RealLev1, ImagLev1)
```

`NSI` is the "scripting routines object", which is working with many other functions and subroutines.

Sadly the code above does not work because (according to the debugger) of a type conflict. So I checked the Classes-Explorer and found out that the `FFPol1Array` class is defined as:

```
get_FFPOL1Array(ByRef System.Array, ByRef System.Array) As Object
set_FFPOL1Array(ByRef System.Array, ByRef System.Array, ByRef Object)
```

Thus I tried to `Dim` my arrays as `System.Array` instad of `Single` but this failed too always because of a type conflict. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it need to be `set vDummy=` ?

Comment: could you post your .NET code ?

Comment: @anefeletos my code is already posted (second block), there is nothing else. It's the code stripped to its minimum, and even this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this was a little ridiculous but I managed to understand that I eventually had to initialize the `Array`s, because the FORTRAN function did not do that:

```
Dim RealLev1 As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)
Dim ImagLev1 As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)
```

This did the job. Even better was:

```
Dim RealLev1(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)
Dim ImagLev1(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan_Sav suggested, get_FFPOL1Array is returning an Object so you need to use Set.

```
Set vDummy = NSI.FFPOL1Array(RealLev1, ImagLev1)
```